# В Webstorm не подчеркивается синтаксис у .HJS файлов

Tags: html, webstorm, jetbrains

Скриншот проблемы прикрепил ниже.
[image: Скриншот Webstorm]

Comment: Слишком стандартный формат, чтобы его понимал `webstorm`. Вы можете выбрать то, каким форматом интерпритировать открытый файл "неизвестного формата"

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев мне как раз и нужно узнать, как это сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Настройках `CTRL+ALT+S`

> Editor -> File Types

В `Recognized File Types` выбрать `HTML` (или нужный вам формат файла)

Добавить в `Registred Patterns` нужный вам формат